# Data manipulation simple

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I have to separate my friend who already have group or not...

```
# All student in class
student_in_class = ["john smith" , "rookie" , "emma" , "olivia" , "tommy"]

student_got_group = "john smith emma olivia" #By text from chatting
student_grouped_splitted = student_got_group.split()


grouped = []
ungrouped = []

for member in student_in_class:
    if member in student_grouped_splitted:
        grouped.append(member)
    else:
        ungrouped.append(member)
```

1. there is bug john smith need to be "john smith" not "john","smith" . I tried :

student_grouped_splitteds = student_got_group.split()
student_grouped_splitted = student_grouped_splitteds.append("john smith")

```
student_grouped_splitteds = student_got_group.split()
student_grouped_splitted = student_grouped_splitteds.append("john smith")
```

but it gave me **TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable**

2. This is hardest... chatting will be like this:

- john smith
- emma
- olivia

when I copy it, they will be like this :

```
student_got_group = "- John Smith
- Emma
- Olivia"
```

I need to remove the new line one by one and there are 30 students in my class. Should I use excel or what because I don't know about excel...

Any insight will be very helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you split the string and don't you just check if the elements of the first list are contained in the string?

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO - What if there is also another student called "John" (not "John Smith")?

Comment: Anyway there wouldn't be any way to discriminate between john smith and john while splitting, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make a new list by splitting on spaces. John Smith has his name splitted by a space, hence the unwanted behavior. I suggest you use the **in** operator instead and use a list comprehension.

```
student_in_class = ["john smith" , "rookie" , "emma" , "olivia" , "tommy"]

student_got_group = "john smith emma olivia" #By text from chatting
student_grouped_splitted = [i for i in student_in_class if i in student_got_group]


grouped = []
ungrouped = []

for member in student_in_class:
    if member in student_grouped_splitted:
        grouped.append(member)
    else:
        ungrouped.append(member)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for member in student_in_class:
    if member in student_got_group: # I changed this line
        grouped.append(member)
    else:
        ungrouped.append(member)
```

Doing this you will solve the issue `#1`, because it won't give you problems with `john smith` since it is `in` the `str`ing.